# React native Expo go -doesnt make http Requests

Tags: reactjs, react-native, post, expo-go

I have react native exo app and I need to make a POST request. On simulator I can do the request but on the Expo go app , I cant. I dont get errors , nothing . I click the button but it doesnt do anything.

I tried to allow on backend all hosts but still the same issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.